# JLabel ToolTip interferes with MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jlabel, mouselistener

I have Java Swing application `ToolTipMouseTest`

The critical line is `label.setToolTipText("label" + i);`. Once it is commented out very click on a label produces `2 mousePressed` in console. With this line enabled click on labels would produce nothing.

**Is this expected behaviour or a bug?** My goal is to show tooltips without disabling `MouseListener` from working.

Almost SSCCE, but without imports:

```
public class ToolTipMouseTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ToolTipMouseTest();
        }
    });
}

public ToolTipMouseTest() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600,400);
        }
    };

    MouseAdapter1 mouseAdapter1 = new MouseAdapter1();
    lpane.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter1);

    frame.add(lpane);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    panel1.setOpaque(false);

    lpane.add(panel1, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label " + i);
        panel2.add(label);
        label.setToolTipText("label" + i); //HERE!!
    }

    JScrollPane spane = new JScrollPane(panel2) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }
    };

    MouseAdapter2 mouseAdapter2 = new MouseAdapter2();
    spane.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter2);

    panel1.add(spane);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private class MouseAdapter1 extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("1 mousePressed");
    }
}

private class MouseAdapter2 extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("2 mousePressed");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is working as intended. Let me explain why.

- When a component has no listener, the mouse events will be propagated.
- When any component has at least one `MouseListener` set on it - it will **consume any** mouse enter/exit/click/press/release events from going down in the components hierarchy.

  It's the same for any listener such as `MouseMotionListener` with
  mouse dragged/moved.
- When you are adding a tooltip to a component (`JLabel` in your case), the component automatically receive a new MouseListener and a `MouseMotionListener` from `ToolTipManager`. The `registerComponent` method from `ToolTipManager` class do this (it's invoked by `setToolTipText`) :

  ```java
  public void registerComponent(JComponent component) {
      component.removeMouseListener(this);
      component.addMouseListener(this);
      component.removeMouseMotionListener(moveBeforeEnterListener);
      component.addMouseMotionListener(moveBeforeEnterListener);
      component.removeKeyListener(accessibilityKeyListener);
      component.addKeyListener(accessibilityKeyListener);
  }
  ```

In your case - `JLabel`s are consuming mouse events and mouse motion events, and as such prevents from propagating the events to the `JLayeredPane` because `ToolTipManager` listener added itself when the tooltip is set (`setToolTipText`) on the component.

In order to work around this, register a listener that will pass events down. You can add that listener to every component with a tooltip that should pass mouse events down (e.g to a `JLayeredPane`, a `JScrollPane`, etc).

Here is a small example of how that could be done:

```java
var destinationComponent = // the JLayeredPane, JScrollPane, etc with mouse listeners

componentWithToolTip.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        destinationComponent.dispatchEvent(
                SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(
                        event.getComponent(), // the component with the tooltip 
                        event,
                        destinationComponent
                )
        );
    }

    // implements other mouse* handlers as required.
});
```

In that setup `componentWithToolTip` will have 2 listeners, the one from the ToolTipManager and the propagating one. When `componentWithToolTip` all its listeners will be triggered, and the propagating listener will dispatch to the declared destination component `destinationComponent`. So that `destinationComponent` listeners receive the mouse events as well.